# Showing that two numbers are the same percent different from their average.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

More specifically, consider two real numbers $a,b>0$, and their average $r=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

It is the case that $a=r*x$ and $b=r*y$ where $\vert 1-x\vert =\vert 1-y\vert$.

For example, let $a=5$ and $b=7$. Then $r=6$, and $a= .833333 r$ and $b=1.1666666 r$.

How can I formally prove this?

> More specifically, is there a way to prove this that isn't by doing the cases $a>b$ and $a<b$ separately?

I ask about doing it without cases because we can write $a= \frac{2a}{a+b} \frac{a+b}{2}$ and $b= \frac{2b}{a+b} \frac{a+b}{2}$

so then we just need to show the relationship between $ \frac{2a}{a+b}$ and $ \frac{2b}{a+b}$

if $a>b$ then $ \frac{2a}{a+b} -1 = \frac{a-b}{a+b} = 1-  \frac{2b}{a+b}$

but if $a<b$ then we need to write $ 1- \frac{2a}{a+b} = \frac{b-a}{a+b} =   \frac{2b}{a+b}-1$

> i.e. depending on if $a>b$ or $b<a$ we write $ \frac{2a}{a+b} -1$ or $ 1- \frac{2a}{a+b} $. Is there a way I can do this proof without cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that 
$$|X|=|Y|\iff X=\pm Y$$
So, we have
$$\begin{align}&|1-x|=|1-y|
\\\\&\iff 1-x=1-y\quad\text{or}\quad 1-x=-(1-y)
\\\\&\iff x=y\quad\text{or}\quad x+y=2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify. $X=\pm Y$ here means $X= Y$ OR $X=-Y$ (if so, then how does that work if $Y=0$, in which case $X=Y$ AND $X=-Y$?)

Comment: @user106860 : (1) Yes, $X=\pm Y$ means "$X=Y$ or $X=-Y$". (2) So, if $Y=0$, then we have "$X=0$ or $X=0$" which is nothing but $X=0$ by the definition of "or" in mathematics.